# data not coming for nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray data as below.

```
{
    Id = "57\n    ";
    Image = "http://www.mysite.com/32f7aff4-9cb2-4044-a555-bfac8ea6eace.gif\n    ";
    NameEn = "salim\n    ";
    SpecializationsEn = "Dentistry\n    ";
}
```

Now I wanted to get Imaage name  hence I tried

```
[[feeds objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Image"]
```

but this is giving me error as

```
-[__NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x759b0b0
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x759b0b0'
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the data structure that you've posted, you don't have an array object but rather a dictionary object and a dictionary won't respond to objectAtIndex:.

Try replacing this:

```
[[feeds objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Image"]
```

With this:

```
[feeds objectForKey:@"Image"]
```

Or, if you prefer modern Objective-C syntax, this:

```
feeds[@"image"];
```

Comment: its giving value, but xcode giving warning `NSMutableArray may not respond to objectForKey`. I believe I need to change NSMutableArray to NSMutableDictionary. Right?

Comment: @FahimParkar Correct. That should solve the problem.

Comment: yep.. solved it :). Will accept answer after 3 mins..

Comment: @FahimParkar Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

If you use NSMutableArray, then you should write`[array valueForKey:@"key"];`to retrieve elements from it

Comment: from Apple documentation valueForKey:
Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.